# Any idea what the syntax error is?

Tags: python

```
car = input("Audi TT + Licence + Tax: 4000")
car = int(car)
insurance = int(input("Insurance: 1500 "))
petrol= int(input("Petrol Per Month: 250*12 "))
dealerprep= int(input(input("Dealer Prep: 2000: "))

total = car + insurance + petrol + dealerprep

print("\nGrand Total :", total)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Apparently the total is an error? I would like to know why it says this as it didnt before. Probably my poor coding!

Comment: Are you trying to pass values to `input` through a prompt? Moreover, `input(input(...))` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `input(input("What question should I ask you?"))`  :p

Comment: @ForceBru wow calm done, i've only just started programming and so I am bound to get things wrong!

Comment: What is your latest error? Copy paste the error please.

Comment: Literally just says syntax error and thats it?

Comment: @ChrisBeldam Does it not say which line the error is on?

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
dealerprep= int(input(input("Dealer Prep: 2000: "))
```

should be

```
dealerprep= int(input("Dealer Prep: 2000: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wait, until you run the program - then enter the inputs.

```
#example.py
car = input("Audi TT + Licence + Tax: ")
car = int(car)
insurance = int(input("Insurance: "))
petrol= int(input("Petrol Per Month: "))
dealerprep= int(input("Dealer Prep: "))

total = car + insurance + petrol + dealerprep

print("\nGrand Total :", total)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

then run,

```
$ python3 example.py 
Audi TT + Licence + Tax: 34
Insurance: 453
Petrol Per Month: 645
Dealer Prep: 64557

Grand Total : 65689
```

Press the enter key to exit. #i pressed enter and program stops to run

One note. If you will input an  expression (like 45*20) you should pass this expression to eval() funxtion.

In your case, if you want to input "Petrol per month" like `45*20`, try

```
petrol= eval(input("Petrol Per Month: "))
```

otherwise it will raise `ValueError`

```
>>> c = int(input("Petrol per Month: "))
Petrol per Month: 45*20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '45*20'
```